# select() doesn't return after timeout

Tags: c, linux, select, fifo

I create one executable file named as "readmsg". Its source code is as below. The `select()` works if I only perform `readmsg` in shell (I can see the output of `timeout`).

But if I create a FIFO file via command: `mknod /tmp/message p`, and perform `readmsg < /tmp/message` in shell. In result, the `select()` can't return if I don't write something in `/tmp/message`. My question is: Why I can't get the `timeout` output?

the source code of "readmsg":

```
    #define STDIN 0
    fd_set fds;
    struct timeval tv;
    while (1) {
        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        FD_SET(STDIN, &fds);
        tv.tv_sec = 1;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;
        ret = select(STDIN + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
        if (ret > 0) {
            printf("works\n");
            if (FD_ISSET(STDIN, &fds)) {
                // read ...
            }
        } else if (ret == 0) {
            printf("timeout!!\n");
        } else {
            printf("interrupt\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: With the pipe, you're probably not reaching the select in the first place. Put some more debug printouts before the select.

Comment: You should print the `errno`, e.g. replace the last `printf` with `printf("failed - %s\n", strerror(errno));`; and you should prefer `poll` to `select` (e.g. because `select` is limiting the maximal file descriptor number thru the size of `fd_set`; Google for *C10K problem* for more).

Comment: Lucky you are on Linux and not Solaris. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html :)

Comment: Also, you might `strace` both your program and the programs writing to the FIFO....

Comment: I assume that the shell blocks while opening the fifo for the redirection. Without `O_NONBLOCK`, `open()` will block if noone has opened the fifo for writing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Mat. After adding `printf()` close to `main()`, there is not output either. Even there is not the process id of `readmsg` when perform `ps`. 
So it proves the process of `readmsg < /tmp/message` is blocked before the FIFO is ready to be writen.

There isn't any error. In fact, the `readmsg` works well when reading messages from redirected FIFO file.